# Best way to store long strings in a mapping?

Tags: solidity

I want users to be able to store long URLs on Etherum.

```
 mapping(address => string[]) public addressToLinks;

UnimplementedFeatureError: Accessors for mapping with dynamically-sized keys not yet implemented.
```

I cant seem to use strings, and there doesn't seem to be a data type for larger bytes, like bytes256.

What is the best way to solve this problem? I'm not opposed to using the new experimental ABI encoder, but I still cant figure out a good solution... (I dont want to use a URL shortener)

I suppose I can store a mapping to a uint index, and have the index take me to a giant 2d array of arrays of strings... but theres gota be a better way....

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compilation error is due to the fact that a getter function for `mapping(any_type => string[])` is not yet supported, so you cannot declare such mapping as `public`.

By the way, this is true not only for `string[]`, but also for `string`.

So change this:

```
mapping(address => string[]) public addressToLinks;
```

To this:

```
mapping(address => string[]) private addressToLinks;
```

Or to this:

```
mapping(address => string[]) internal addressToLinks;
```

And add this:

```
function getLink(address key, uint index) external view returns (string) {
    return addressToLinks[key][index];
}
```